# C: Iterate through SQLite records and assigning each value to a variable

Tags: sql, c, sqlite, variables

I have table USER with columns ID, NAME and ADDRESS. e.g.

Column ID has 1,2
Column NAME has Bob, Jane
Column ADDRESS has UK, US

And I wish to iterate through all records and save each column into an array. The result would be something like this:

char *NAME[2];
NAME[0] would have "Bob", NAME[1] would have "Jane" and

char *ADDRESS[2];
ADDRESS[0] would have "UK", ADDRESS[1] would have "US".

Can someone point me in the right direction instead of calling an SQL statement for each array entry?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a zillion tutorials online, which have you read?

Comment: I've seen a few (e.g. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm) but they only show how to display ALL records, but none show how to iterate through rows and most importantly, save each value into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start with the SELECT example in the tutorial you linked to, you can modify it to have a

```
struct results {
  size_t num_used;
  char* NAME[SOME_MAX_NUMBER_OF_ROWS_HERE];
  char* ADDRESS[SOME_MAX_NUMBER_OF_ROWS_HERE];
};
```

and then have one of those on your stack (with num_used set to 0) and pass a pointer to that as argument 4 of `sqlite3_exec`. In `callback`, you then cast argument 1 to a pointer to `struct results`, and `strdup` your fields to `results->NAME[results->num_used]` etc., and increment `results->num_used` at the end. When `sqlite3_exec` returns, you should have your `NAME` and `ADDRESS` arrays filled out.

There are of course better ways of handling the arrays, so that you don't have to anticipate the maximum number of rows etc., but that's a different issue.

Comment: Thank you good sir! I read this and realized that callback is invoked at every record. It also did not occur to me that a struct can be used.